# How to access data in mounted() with nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I tried to do a for loop inside a mounted() function with nuxt.js. The data I tried to loop through was called with axios in created() but when I log the data in created() I get this object:

```
[__ob__: Observer]
```

mounted:

```
mounted() {
        // creating FeaturedCasinos
        for(let i = 0; i > this.casinos.length; i++) {
            console.log("loop")
            if(this.casinos[i].brand_tags[2].Brand_Tag_Name = "Featured") {
                this.featuredCasinos.push(this.casinos[i]);
            }
        }
    },
```

created:

```
created() {
return axios.get("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/casinos/").then(res2 => (this.casinos = res2.data))
}
```

EDIT:

```
 asyncData({ params }) {
        return axios.get(casinoURL + params.casinos).then(res => {
            return { 
                casino: res.data, 
                casinoID: res.data[0].id, 
                casinoBonus: res.data[0].bonuses,
                casinoPros: res.data[0].brand_pros,
                casinoCons: res.data[0].brand_cons,
                casinoGames: res.data[0].verticals,
                casinoTags: res.data[0].brand_tags,
                casinoPayments: res.data[0].payment_methods,
                casinoDeposits: res.data[0].Deposit_Methods,
                casinoWithdrawals: res.data[0].Withdrawal_Methods,
                casinoLanguages: res.data[0].languages,
                casinoGamingProvider: res.data[0].gaming_provider,
                casinoAnswers: res.data.map(item => { return {FAQ_Answer_One:item.FAQ_Answer_One, FAQ_Answer_Two:item.FAQ_Answer_Two, FAQ_Answer_Three:item.FAQ_Answer_Three, FAQ_Answer_Four:item.FAQ_Answer_Four, FAQ_Answer_Five:item.FAQ_Answer_Five, FAQ_Answer_Six:item.FAQ_Answer_Six}})
            };
        })
    },
    asyncData({ params }) {
        return axios.get("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/casinos/").then(res2 => {
            return { casinos: res2.data }
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data):

> You do NOT have access to the component instance through this inside asyncData because it is called before initializing the component.

So instead in `asyncData` you should return the data that will be merged with the component data as an object:

```js
asyncData({ params }) {
  return axios.get("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/casinos/").then(res2 => {
    return { casinos: res2.data }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: in this new case after you edited the question you should delete one of the `asyncData` and retrieve the unified data. You may use the async/await syntax to make the code more clear and easier to read:

```js
asyncData({ params }) {
  const res = await axios.get(casinoURL + params.casinos)
  const res2 = await axios.get("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/casinos/")

  return { 
    casino: res.data, 
    casinoID: res.data[0].id, 
    casinoBonus: res.data[0].bonuses,
    casinoPros: res.data[0].brand_pros,
    casinoCons: res.data[0].brand_cons,
    casinoGames: res.data[0].verticals,
    casinoTags: res.data[0].brand_tags,
    casinoPayments: res.data[0].payment_methods,
    casinoDeposits: res.data[0].Deposit_Methods,
    casinoWithdrawals: res.data[0].Withdrawal_Methods,
    casinoLanguages: res.data[0].languages,
    casinoGamingProvider: res.data[0].gaming_provider,
    casinoAnswers: res.data.map(item => { return {FAQ_Answer_One:item.FAQ_Answer_One, FAQ_Answer_Two:item.FAQ_Answer_Two, FAQ_Answer_Three:item.FAQ_Answer_Three, FAQ_Answer_Four:item.FAQ_Answer_Four, FAQ_Answer_Five:item.FAQ_Answer_Five, FAQ_Answer_Six:item.FAQ_Answer_Six}})
    casinos: res2.data
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to do that but I get an error this might be because I have two asyncData functions on the page. I edited the answer.